# Slide down/up with ngAnimate?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want to add simple slide done/up animation. As an example, if you go to [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) you can see left-side panel, where you can add external resources, Ajax requests and so on. If click on some of those you can see simple animated slide down effect. What I am trying to achieve is a bit similar. I have an html button:

```
<button class="checkbox-button btn btn-primary" ng-click="updateActiveTypeBox(true)">{{typeBoxMessage}}</button>
```

And here is my check-boxes div:

```
<div ng-show="activeTypeBox">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectAll.selected" ng-click="checkAll()" />Check All
        </label>
        <label ng-repeat="carType in carTypeObj">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="carType.selected" /> {{carType.type}}
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

When you click on the button, `activeTypeBox` is set to `true`, so `ng-show="activeTypeBox"` passes. When you click on this button again, `activeTypeBox` is set to `false`, so `ng-show="activeTypeBox"` fails. The only thing that I need to add is slide down/up animation. I prefer to use Angular-Animate because it is library that works with angular code. I have tried to find the solution, but I did't find the one that fits my requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

Looks like it can be done with CSS:

```
.animate-show {
  line-height:20px;
  opacity:1;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid black;
  background:white;
}

.animate-show.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active,
.animate-show.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
  -webkit-transition:all linear 0.5s;
  transition:all linear 0.5s;
}

.animate-show.ng-hide {
  line-height:0;
  opacity:0;
  padding:0 10px;
}
```

so just add `class="animate-show"` for the div

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow#usage_animations

a working example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/xmkBjvPY5OjFLnxcuVKz?p=preview&s=jBzeCEpWphlOpSRv

Comment: it is still the same. Just showing up and hiding without any animation.

Comment: note: i did add "ngAnimate" as my module dependency

Comment: I'm looking in the API, you will hear from me soon :)